# Gunicorn with Flask raises "Error handling request" at end of request

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm using Flask with Gunicorn using the "gevent" worker. The request completes, the client receives the response, and Gunicorn spits out "Error handling request", and then waits for a new request.

This is the stacktrace:

```
2014-07-12 18:01:53 [38427] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 38427
2014-07-12 18:01:55 [38427] [DEBUG] POST /job/dev/job1
2014-07-12 18:01:55 [38427] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dustin/development/python/mapreduce/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py", line 116, in handle_request
    raise StopIteration()
StopIteration
```

(I should note that this is coming out of the "async" worker module, and not the intended "gevent" one).

This is the relevant portion of that module:

```
    except Exception:
        if resp and resp.headers_sent:
            # If the requests have already been sent, we should close the
            # connection to indicate the error.
            self.log.exception("Error handling request")
            try:
                sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                sock.close()
            except socket.error:
                pass
            raise StopIteration()
        raise
    finally:
```

Does anyone have any experience with this? I'm a long time user of Gunicorn, but haven't used Flask very often. I'm guessing that Flask is doing something to have the headers sent back early.

Comment: Is your application running with a synchronous worker? Is this happen only on special routes or is every request broken?

Comment: As mentioned, using "gevent" worker.